# How to use a custom method in form to send request and accept response from another server in Django?

Tags: django, forms, methods

I have the following code in my `forms.py` file.

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    employee_id = forms.CharField(label='Employee ID', max_length=30)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Retype Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', max_length=100)
    designation = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    department = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in departments])
    mobile = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2:
            if password1 != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError(("The two password fields didn't match."))
            elif password1 == '' or password2 == '':
                raise forms.ValidationError(("The password cannot be blank"))
        return password2
```

I have two queries.

1. I understand how the code in the `clean_password2` method works but I don't understand why that method is called `clean_password2` and why does it not work if I remove the `2` from the name?
2. I have a script in another server where I want to send a request with `employee_id` and get a response back whether that ID is available or it already exists. How do I create a method that would not let me submit the form in the ID is not available?

Also, it would be highly helpful if someone provides me with reading material to get a solid grasp on `Django Forms`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Most solid docs** for django are official ones [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/) and [their validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/)

1) In docs

> The `clean_<fieldname>()` method is called on a form subclass – where `<fieldname>` is replaced with the name of the form field attribute. This method does any cleaning that is specific to that particular attribute, unrelated to the type of field that it is. This method is not passed any parameters. You will need to look up the value of the field in self.cleaned_data and remember that it will be a Python object at this point, not the original string submitted in the form (it will be in cleaned_data because the general field clean() method, above, has already cleaned the data once).

Which means this validation method starting with clean gets called only if it has corresponding field. Which is why `password2` works and `password` don't.

2) You can do this with `clean_<fieldname>`. Here is example

```
def clean_employee_id(self):
    value = self.cleaned_data['employee_id']
    # send request to your remote server. I would suggest using requests library
    if remote_check_is_successful:
        return value
    raise ValidationError('invalid employee_id')
```

Take into account that there may be some networking errors other than validation itself, also if remote server replies slowly form submit will take a long time and this is not very userfriendly. But this whole another question

Answer (score 1):

As for reading materials - django docs is the best source. For example, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation

> The `clean_<fieldname>()` method is called on a form subclass – where
>   `<fieldname>` is replaced with the name of the form field attribute.
>   This method does any cleaning that is specific to that particular
>   attribute, unrelated to the type of field that it is.

So your clean_password2 method is called to validate password2 field. It does not work without "2" because your form does not have "password" field. And if you want custom validation for validate employee_id field you would need to put it to clean_employee_id method.